# Can't upload an Image due to DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, crop, image-gallery

I am using an Image cropper library called [ImageCropper.Forms](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms/), which when I finish selecting an image from the gallery it crops it and attaches it to the `Image`.

So I tried to access the Image Source in order to utilize it for uploading, but am getting this error.

Actually, this library has also another library in it called [Xam.Plugin.Media](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) , which helps to select images from the gallery or take photos with the camera.

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path "/File:
>   /data/user/0/com.nl.via/cache/cropped5748405962114920444.jpg".
>         at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access,
>   System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean
>   anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001 ...

I thought it would be able to pick the `Image/ picture` **path** but it didn't work, what went wrong.

This is how I get a cropped picture and I attach it to the `Image`:

```
private void SelectImageFromGallery(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = "";
            new ImageCropper
            {
                CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
                Success = imageFile =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        //profile_img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return _mediaFile.GetStream(); });
                        profile_img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                        Debug.WriteLine("filepath2 " + path);
                    });
                }
            }.Show(this);

            Debug.WriteLine("filepath " + path);
        }
```

Then after attaching the Pick, I upload the pick to the server :

```
private async void UploadImage(){
            try
            {
                ai.IsRunning = true;
                ai.IsVisible = true;


                var token = Application.Current.Properties["token"].ToString();

                var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                Console.WriteLine("filepath2--:" + profile_img.Source);



                // Convert it into bytes.
                var readAllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(profile_img.Source.ToString());

                var baContent = new ByteArrayContent(readAllBytes);

                multiForm.Add(new StringContent(XValue.ToString()), X);
                multiForm.Add(new StringContent(YValue.ToString()), Y);
                multiForm.Add(new StringContent("60"), Width);
                multiForm.Add(new StringContent("60"), Height);

                multiForm.Add(baContent, "image", Path.GetFileName(_mediaFile.AlbumPath));

                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(Settings.BaseUrl + "/auth/Users/ChangeAvatar", multiForm);

}
```

So if you clearly see the uploading part the error occurs on this line :

```
// Convert it into bytes.
var readAllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(profile_img.Source.ToString());
```

*So am wondering what could be the best approach of uploading a cropped image?*

**EDIT:**

When I used *Device File Explorer* , I see a different path with no `user/0/`, below is an Image , the path is `data/com.nl.via/cache/cropped1030309698891957373.jpg`:

[image]

But the one which is printed is `data/user/0/com.nl.via/cache/cropped1030309698891957373.jpg`.

Comment: I'm just curious: what does `Directory.Exists(profile_img.Source.ToString())` say?

Comment: Also, what did your `Console.WriteLine("filepath2--:" + profile_img.Source);` say?

Comment: When I console logged, I got this `/data/user/0/com.nl.via/cache/cropped1030309698891957373.jpg”`. @TylerMarshall

Comment: @mu88, let try out that.

Comment: @mu88, it returns `False`, but what could be the best way of getting the correct one.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course I meant `File.Exists(profile_img.Source.ToString())`

Comment: @mu88, it's also returning `False`

Comment: @mu88 , I have updated my question, I included the directories of the app, kindly check it out.

Comment: @TylerMarshall , I have updated my question, I included the directories of the app, kindly check it out.

Comment: See [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/what-kind-of-data-is-stored-in-data-user-directory): `/data/user/0` seems to be a symlink. Maybe it is not handled properly, so please try to replace it with `/data` or `/data/data`

Comment: Actually I have replaced, but still, the same error, am wondering why 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store the file to your app's local storage:

```
var path = "";
new ImageCropper
{
    CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
    Success = imageFile =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            //profile_img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return _mediaFile.GetStream(); });
            profile_img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
            Debug.WriteLine("filepath2 " + path);

            var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            File.Copy(imageFile, Path.Combine(folderPath, "image.png"));
        });
    }
}.Show(this);
```

Then use this local path to read the file:

```
var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
// Keep it the same as the file name when you store it
File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(folderPath, "image.png"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but does it mean I have to do this :

`
  `var readAllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(folderPath, "image.png"));`

   `var baContent = new ByteArrayContent(readAllBytes);`

Comment: Maybe the other question would be, can you kindly show the path of `localApplicationData` ?

Comment: `localApplicationData` this is the app's own local internal folder path. You could debug it to see the path value. `Path.Combine(folderPath, "image.png")` is a file path, you can replace the second parameter if you want to define it as another file name. But you have to retrieve it using the same file path. I update the answer for telling you to use the same file name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your path to the image is right, because I think the path you pasted is wrong because of the `/File:` at the beginning of that, seems you should split that part and use the rest which is the path you really want to use

Try to check if the directory that you're trying to read from is created with this.

`Directory.Exists(profile_img.Source.ToString())`

Also could be a problem with permissions, but maybe I'm wrong because of the fact I'm not familiar with Android :)

Comment: It returned `false`, it's what @mu88 , was saying , but am trying out his new suggestion.

Comment: Does the path `/data/user/0/com.nl.via/cache` is created in your device?

Comment: yeah it is created.

Comment: Is you server-side inside your application or you sending a request to an API/service?

I think your passing an argument to the server-side with the path of your device, which can't be read because you're in the server-side. If I'm right the you should send your image in base64 and store it in your server for example

Comment: Hey , I have updated my question, kindly checkout the last part.

Comment: Am trying to pick the Image path and then send it to the server.

Comment: Oh, I see your edit. Have you tried with the path without the `user/0`part? 

I have updated my past comment too, check it!

Comment: Actually , after replace the I get this path , `/data/data/com.nl.via/cache/cropped1030309698891957373.jpg`, but still brings the same error. maybe if possible we a hangouts call on huxaiphaeridris@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193491/discussion-between-idris-stack-and-jase).